# PostgreSQL: insert data into table from json

Tags: json, postgresql, insert

Now I use to manually parse json into insert string like so

```
insert into Table (field1, field2) values (val1, val2)
```

but its not comfortable way to insert data from json!
I've found function json_populate_record and tried to use it:

```
create table test (id serial, name varchar(50));
insert into test select * from json_populate_record(NULL::test, '{"name": "John"}');
```

but it fails with the message: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
PG knows that id is serial but pretends to be a fool. Same it do for all fieds with defaults.

Is there more elegant vay to insert data from json into a table?

Comment: "I found function `json_populate_record`". Um. *Where*? What's the function definition? Are you running PostgreSQL 9.3 beta, or is it a function you installed from somewhere else?

Comment: It's 9.3 beta's function

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's no easy way for `json_populate_record` to return a marker that means "generate this value".

PostgreSQL does *not* allow you to insert `NULL` to specify that a value should be generated. If you ask for `NULL` Pg expects to *mean* `NULL` and doesn't want to second-guess you. Additionally it's perfectly OK to have a generated column that has no `NOT NULL` constraint, in which case it's perfectly fine to insert `NULL` into it.

If you want to have PostgreSQL use the table default for a value there are two ways to do this:

- Omit that row from the `INSERT` column-list; or
- Explicitly write `DEFAULT`, which is only valid in a `VALUES` expression

Since you can't use `VALUES(DEFAULT, ...)` here, your only option is to omit the column from the `INSERT` column-list:

```
regress=# create table test (id serial primary key, name varchar(50));
CREATE TABLE
regress=# insert into test(name) select name from json_populate_record(NULL::test, '{"name": "John"}');
INSERT 0 1
```

Yes, this means you must list the columns. Twice, in fact, once in the `SELECT` list and once in the `INSERT` column-list.

To avoid the need for that this PostgreSQL would need to have a way of specifying `DEFAULT` as a value for a record, so `json_populate_record` could return `DEFAULT` instead of `NULL` for columns that aren't defined. That might not be what you intended for all columns and would lead to the question of how `DEFAULT` would be treated when `json_populate_record` was *not* being used in an `INSERT` expression.

So I guess `json_populate_record` might be less useful than you hoped for rows with generated keys.

Comment: very cool. is there a way to `UPDATE` too, based on a json input ?

Comment: @jney I'm not really sure what you're asking. I suggest posting a new properly detailed question and linking back to this one for context.

Comment: Very useful information (documentation for `json_populate_record` is a bit sparse). But there really does seem to be a good case for an option to the effect of "where no value specified, use the default".

Answer (score 14):

Continuing from [Craig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17908760/290182), you probably need to write some sort of stored procedure to perform the necessary dynamic SQL, like as follows:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsoninsert(relname text, reljson text)
  RETURNS record AS
$BODY$DECLARE
 ret RECORD;
 inputstring text;
BEGIN
  SELECT string_agg(quote_ident(key),',') INTO inputstring
    FROM json_object_keys(reljson::json) AS X (key);
  EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO '|| quote_ident(relname) 
    || '(' || inputstring || ') SELECT ' ||  inputstring 
    || ' FROM json_populate_record( NULL::' || quote_ident(relname) || ' , json_in($1)) RETURNING *'
    INTO ret USING reljson::cstring;
  RETURN ret;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Which you'd then call with

```sql
SELECT jsoninsert('test', '{"name": "John"}');
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for! Saved after many hours of searching. If I wanted the return value to be in json object form, just as in the input value, how would this be achieved?

Comment: Glad it helped. If you wanted to return the JSON, I guess change to `RETURNS json` and instead or `RETURN ret` try `RETURN row_to_json(ret)`. I haven't tested, but that's the general idea.